# Python Brainf*ck interpreter

Tags: python, performance, interpreter, brainfuck

What do you think of my Brainf*ck interpreter?
What else can be done to increase speed?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class InfiniteArray:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pstack, self.nstack = [], []
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        s = self.pstack if index >= 0 else self.nstack
        i = index if index >= 0 else -index + 1
        if i >= len(s):
            return 0
        return s[i]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        s = self.pstack if index >= 0 else self.nstack
        i = index if index >= 0 else -index - 1
        if i >= len(s):
            s.extend([0 for _ in range(len(s), i+1 + 100)])
        s[i] = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(reversed(self.nstack))) + ' | ' + str(self.pstack)


class StateMachine:
    def __init__(self, code, jump_table, debug=False):
        self.arr = InfiniteArray()
        self.pointer = 0
        self.i = 0
        self.code = code
        self.jt = jump_table
        self.debug = debug
        self.instrcount = 0

    def putc(self):
        from sys import stdout
        stdout.write(chr(self.arr[self.pointer]))
        stdout.flush()

    def getc(self):
        from sys import stdin
        c = stdin.read(1)
        self.arr[self.pointer] = ord(c)

    def plus1(self):
        self.arr[self.pointer] += 1

    def minus1(self):
        self.arr[self.pointer] -= 1

    def mvright(self):
        self.pointer += 1

    def mvleft(self):
        self.pointer -= 1

    def matchl(self):
        if not self.arr[self.pointer]:
            self.i = self.jt[self.i]

    def matchr(self):
        if self.arr[self.pointer]:
            self.i = self.jt[self.i]

    def nextcell(self):
        self.i += 1
        self.instrcount += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.arr) + '\n\n' + ''.join(map(str, self.code))

    def run(self):
        import datetime as dt
        ops = {'+': self.plus1,
               '-': self.minus1,
               '>': self.mvright,
               '<': self.mvleft,
               '.': self.putc,
               ',': self.getc,
               '[': self.matchl,
               ']': self.matchr }
        start = dt.datetime.now()
        while self.i < len(self.code):
            c = self.code[self.i]
            ops[c]()
            self.nextcell()
            if self.debug:
                print(self)
        end = dt.datetime.now()
        print(int(self.instrcount/(end-start).microseconds * 10**6), "instr/second")


def extract(file):
    code = []
    for c in file.read():
        if c in '><+-.,[]':
            code.append(c)
    jump_table = dict()
    stack = []
    count = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(code):
        if count < 0:
            raise SyntaxError("2muh ]")
        if c == '[':
            stack.append(i)
            count += 1
        if c == ']':
            jump_table[i] = stack[-1]
            jump_table[stack[-1]] = i
            stack.pop()
            count -= 1
    if count > 0:
        raise SyntaxError("unmatched [ at positions " + ', '.join(map(str, stack)))

    return code, jump_table

def main():
    from sys import argv
    options = {'debug': False}
    for i, name in enumerate(argv[1:]):
        print('no. {}: {}'.format(i+1, name))
        try:
            if name == '-':
                f = open('/dev/stdin')
            elif name.startswith('-'):
                if name == '-debug':
                    options['debug'] = True
                continue
            else:
                f = open(name)
        except:
            print("Error: no such file :<")
            continue
        try:
            code, mt = extract(f)
            f.close()
        except SyntaxError as e:
            print("Error:", e)
        finally:
            s = StateMachine(code, mt, debug=options['debug'])
            s.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't mean to be a stickler, but it should be noted that brainfuck doesn't print out errors, or debug.

Answer (score 3):

This looks really nice to me, I have just a few minor remarks.

#### Imports buried in the code

Many imports are buried in some functions,
for example in `putc` and `getc`,
and I don't see a good reason for that.
It would be better to import the required modules at the top.

#### Complicated command line argument parsing

The command line argument parsing in the `main` function looks a bit complicated. I think it should be possible to refactor that to make it easier to read, and using a context manager for the input file handling.

#### Mutually exclusive `if` statements

The second `if` here should be an `elif`:

> ```
> if c == '[':
>     stack.append(i)
>     count += 1
> if c == ']':
>     jump_table[i] = stack[-1]
>     jump_table[stack[-1]] = i
> ```

#### Don't repeat yourself

The assignment of `s` and `i` are almost identical in these two functions:

> ```
> def __getitem__(self, index):
>     s = self.pstack if index >= 0 else self.nstack
>     i = index if index >= 0 else -index + 1
>     # ...
>
> def __setitem__(self, index, value):
>     s = self.pstack if index >= 0 else self.nstack
>     i = index if index >= 0 else -index - 1
>     # ...
> ```

I would add some helper functions to reduce the duplication.

#### Too dense formatting

It would be easier to read the code with a blank line between functions.

Comment: I was asking primarily about performance, but nonetheless good answer.